# How to best add multiple fields to a object

Tags: python, class

This is more a question of "technique". I am trying to create a class in Python that will have a certain number of variables. What would be the best way to store them?

I would like some sort of structure that allows me to quickly retrieve the values without writing further functions:

```
a = myclass()
a.add('name','John')
a.add('age',30)
b = myclass()
b.add('a complete different attribute','value')
```

and then:

```
print a.name
John
```

or

```
print a.retrieve('name')
John
```

I know I can do that by having a two columns list on the class that gets populated when I do add and write a function that retrieves a certain value. But I was wondering if Python had something already built in so reading the code is simplified.

Thanks

Comment: `getattr()`, `setattr()` will allow you to get and set one field at a time. There's no way to add multiple fields in a single call, but you can fetch multiple values using `operator.attrgetter('name', 'age')(a)`.

Comment: Thanks Ashwini! That's very close to what I need!!!! (If you paste your answer as an answer below I can mark it as working)

Comment: thanks everyone! I think that both the setter and dictionary methods are good. Maybe the dictionary is better for my needs here as I may have hundreds of variables and I don't want to have object.my10000variable! So maybe putting everything inside the dic{} is the cleanest implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the class have a dictionary variable, and add would keep adding to that dictionary variable, and then you can use `a.dictvariable['<your variable>']` . A dictionary is a data structure that stores key:value pairs.

Example (python3):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}

    def add(self, name, val):
        self.dict[name] = val

    def get(self, name):
        self.dict.get(name)
```

Then you can use your code as:

```
a = MyClass()
a.add('name','John')
a.add('age',30)
b = MyClass()
b.add('a complete different attribute','value')
print(a.get('name'))
print(b.get('a complete different attribute'))
```

Using dict.get , would make sure that if the 'name' does not exist in the dict, it returns null. Another way to access dictionary variables is -

`dict['name']`

This would return the value store in 'name' key in that dictionary.
But if the 'name' does not exist in the dictionary it would throw `KeyError` .

Alternatively, you can use `setattr()` , like below:

```
class MyClass:
    pass

a = MyClass()
setattr(a, 'name', 'John')
print(a.name)
```

Or you can create your own warpper function in MyClass, that would in turn call `setattr()` . Example :

```
class MyClass:
    def add(self, name, val):
        setattr(self, name, val)

a = MyClass()
a.add('name','John')
print(a.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for "getter and setter methods" as they are often called in OO.  Fortunately they are built in to python classes!

```
class A:
   pass
dir(A)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

`__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` are the names of the private methods and you can invoke them by calling getattr and setattr on an instance of your class, like so:

```
a = A()
setattr(a, "foo", "bar")
print(a.foo)
bar
getattr(a, "foo", None)
'bar'
```

The second argument to getattr is to ensure a default value for variable foo -- None is the default.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that the definition of dictionaries in Python?

```
a = {}
a['name'] = 'John'
a['age'] = 30
b = {}
b['a complete different attribute'] = 'value'
```

This technique is highly optimized: The indices are hashes, and as such very fast. You can 'hide' the dict:

```
class myclass(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self = {}

    def add(self, key, el):
        self[key] = el

    def retrieve(self, key):
        return self[key]

def main():
    a = myclass()
    a.add('name','John')
    a.add('age',30)
    b = myclass()
    b.add('a complete different attribute','value')

    print(a.retrieve('name'))

    return 0
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*